# Knockout select list value on change show/hide second select list

Tags: knockout.js

I am using MVC 5 and Knockout to create a page where names will be listed and against each name there is a selection list (uniform data for all the rows). On 'applyBinding' visible-binding and css-binding works but on subsequent change of selection of list item the modified rows does not respect either binding.
My script is...

```
function Names(data){
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.reqStatus = ko.observable(data.reqStatus);
    self.rejReason = ko.observable(data.rejReason);
    self.showReason = ko.observale(false);

    self.reqStatus.subscribe(function(newValue){
        if (newValue == 2){
            self.showReason = true;
        }
    });

    self.statusCss = ko.computed(function(){
        if (self.reqStatus() == 2) {
            return "rejected";
        }else if (self.showReason() == true){
            return "rejected";
        }else{
            return "accepted";
        }
    });
}

function Reason(data){
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.text = ko.observable(data.text);
}

var reasons = ko.observableArray([]);
$.getJSON(....gets Reason JSON....) 

function Status(data){
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.title = ko.observable(data.title);
}

var listItems = ko.observableArray([]);
$.getJSON(....gets Status JSON....)
```

is used to populate listItems array

```
function ViewModel(data){
    var self = this;
    self.names = ko.observableArray(data);
    $getJson(...gets Names JSON .....) - to fetch and map data

    self.Save = function(){
        // Code to save data.
        jsonArray = ko.toJSON(this.names);
        // Here I can see that the select list value change has been effected in observableArray of 'names'!
    }

    self.acceptCount = ko.computed(function(){
        var acc = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(.... to get the value);
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

My HTML...

```
<div>
   <p> Total Accepted :<span data-bind="text: acceptCount"></span></p>
   <table>
       <tbody data-bind="foreach: names">
           <tr data-bind="css: statusCss">
               <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
               <td><select data-bind="options: listItems, optionText: 'title', optionValue:'id', value: reqStatus"></select> </td>
               <td><select data-bind="options: reasons, optionText: 'text', optionValue:'id', value: rejReason, visible: showReason" ></select></td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

When I load page; visible-binding and CSS-binding works great. 
1 - The problem is when selected list item is changed the required visible-binding and CSS-binding does not happen. However, when I click on Save button and convert array to JSON, I can see that the changes in selected list item are there so why not binding is happening?
2 - When I change select list item (the first one); there is an error if select the value which will cause CSS change...

> JavaScript runtime error: Function expected

This error is raised here

```
self.statusCss = ko.computed(function(){
        if (self.reqStatus() == 2) {
            return "rejected";
        }else if (self.showReason() == true){ // <--- error here
            return "rejected";
        }else{
            return "accepted";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem which was actually a minor mistake...in my computed property i was accessing the observed property more than once and that was the reason it was not returning proper values and script error was raised. The modified code is...

```
    self.statusCss= ko.computed(function () {
        var selectedVal = self.reqStatus();
        if (selectedVal) {
            if (selectedVal === 2) {
                return "rejected";
            } else if (selectedVal === 7) {
                return "late";
            }
        };
    });
```